# ASP C# VS2013 how do i deploy it?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am used to Windows apps in VS.
Now I am doing my first ASP app.
It works using Debug build. 
I have IIS ready to go and the web page (startpage.aspx, haven't needed to rename it yet) is accessible remotely using a Debug build.
Now I want to do a Release build so VS does not need to be running, but no exe gets produced in any directory.

What gets produced, and where?
Do I use Build|Deploy Solution or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exe file for web app, because it will be executed in the browser.

RightClick your project in solution tab and select PUBLISH.

Publish is a creator, which helps you create connection to IIS and deploy webApp.

Depending on your IIS settings - you need to choose a proper way to do it.
If IIS resides on the same machine - you can use FileSystem publish method.

Comment: IIS is on the same machine, but the choices I get are: Microsoft Azure Websites, Import, Custom, Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines

Comment: Normally in Publish Profile selection, there should be <New profile> item - which allows your to create new connection, where you choose type: FileSystem. Probably you'll find it under Custom. Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: Custom asks for a profile name, no filesystem option

Comment: Is there <New Profile> item in Custom? (FileSystem is a publish method and will be selected in connection tab)

Comment: Try all the options you have. Google for details of Publish Web dialog of your specific VS version. Don't expect everything to be done for you.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. It turned out to want a new name not an existing name.  So I published it to a directory and it created a .dll
Now how do I connect the IIS virtual dir to it?  Import in IIS wants a .zip, do I manually make that?  What files will need to be in it?